# Multiple applications using Oculus Rift

Tags: c#, windows, oculus

Is it possible to run two applications using the Oculus Rift?
The first application will be used as a normal Oculus Rift application and will display your desktop ([www.vrdesktop.net](http://www.vrdesktop.net)) and the second one will only ask the Rift some tracking information (such as orientation) so this one doesn't use the display.

Using Win 8.1 x64, second application will be programmed in C#.

Comment: Why don't you try it? There's nothing stopping you from making a test project and trying to run it along the other one. That way you'll know if it works for your specific environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  As many applications as you want can access the tracking information at once.  I believe multiple applications can also access the display, although only the one that has focus will actually show anything.